# background image size for mobile devices

Tags: android, mobile, screen-resolution

I want to show a background image in my andriod application.
What is the ideal image size (width and height) to fit in all screen resolutions for mobile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

id say ideal would be to use the highest screen density so the app will scale it down for lower screen resolutions that way you wont loose quality on bigger screens, heres the chart i got off of here

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
Generalised Dpi values for screens:

ldpi Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi)
mdpi Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline     density.)
hdpi Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
Therefore generalised size of your resources (assuming they are full screen):

ldpi
Vertical = 426 * 120 / 160 = 319.5px
Horizontal = 320 * 120 / 160 = 240px
mdpi
Vertical = 470 * 160 / 160 = 470px
Horizontal = 320 * 160 / 160 = 320px
hdpi
Vertical = 640 * 240 / 160 = 960px
Horizontal = 480 * 240 / 160 = 720px
xhdpi
Vertical = 960 * 320 / 160 = 1920px
Horizontal = 720 * 320 / 160 = 1440px

px = dp*dpi/160
```

Comment: also remind that with recently released Galaxy S4, you may want to add xxhdpi to support wider range of densities.

Answer (score 1):

please refer following links..

- [Support multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
- [Best practise](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence)
- [testing for multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing)

This along with @JRowan answer will guide you in proper direction..